# Disable SSL on a specific URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I want to disable https from a single link, forcing it to http.

https://tipografiasartore.it/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

I added this string to my .htaccess file but it ain't working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My .htaccess so far:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to do this? I don't know the answer to your question, just curious?

Comment: I'm just testing an Exchange service that will be fetching data from this url

Answer (score 1):

You can  use the following  Rule to redirect `https://tipografiasartore.it/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` to its `http` version

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've added this code to the bottom of the .htaccess but I still cannot visit the http version. I've updated my .htaccess code above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this code. Surely it will going to work.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]